# Perl: How to extract sequences based on gene number and nucleotide length?

Tags: regex, perl, fasta

I have 2 files, as follows:

file1.txt:

```
0  117nt, >gene_73|GeneMark.hm... *
0   237nt, >gene_3097|GeneMark.... *
0   237nt, >gene_579|GeneMark.h... *
0   237nt, >gene_988|GeneMark.h... *
0   189nt, >gene_97|GeneMark.hm... *
0   183nt, >gene_97|GeneMark.hm... *
```

file2.fasta:

> >gene_735|GeneMark.hmm|237_nt|+|798985|799221
>   TTGTGGTTCGTGCCGCGCGACGCGTTGCGTCTGCAAACGCCCGACGAAGACATCGCGACCTATCTGTTCAACAAGCATGTGATTCGGCATCGGTTCTGTCCGACCTGCGGGATTCATCCGTTCGCGGAAGGCACGGACCCGAAGGGCAACGCGATGGCGGCCGTCAATCTTCGCTGCGTCGACGGCGTCGATCTCGACGCGTTGAGCGTCCGCCATTTCGACGGGCGCGCGCTCTGA
>   >gene_579|GeneMark.hmm|237_nt|+|667187|667423
>   ATGTACCACGGCGCCGAATTTGCCGCTGCCAAGGGCATGCGCTGGCTGCGAGATGCCGCCAACGGCTCTGCCTTCATCGCACCGGGCAGTCCGTGGCAAAACGGTTTCGTCGAGCGTTTCAACGGCAAGCTGCATGACGAATTGCTGAACCGGGAATGGTTCCGCGGCCGTGCCGAGACCAAGATGCTCATCGAACGCTCCGGCTACGGTCCGTCGAGTCTGACCGGATTCCGATGA
>   >gene_1876|GeneMark.hmm|234_nt|-|2168498|2168731
>   ATGCTGTTCTTTTCGCGCGCGGGCGTGTCGCGTGCGGCCGGCGGCCAATCATGCGGCGAGTCGTTTTGTCGCGGCTCGCGGCGCTTGCCGACGTTGGAATCGCGCGCGCCGATGCGCGGATCGGGGCGGCAACGTTTGCGTATGAGGAATGATGCGTTTGCGCATCGGGAATGGGCGCCTCGCCCCGGTTTCGCCGCGATTCCGCCCGACTCGAGGCAGTCGTTTTTCCGCTAA
>   >gene_3097|GeneMark.hmm|237_nt|-|3467022|3467258
>   GTGTCGAACGAACGTCGCGGCGAACGGCCGCTGCGGGCATCGCCGCAGGACGTCACACGGCGAACGTCGCGCGCGATCCTCGGCGGCCGCGAACGTGGGCCGTCCCGTGGCACGTTCGGCTCGCTCGGCATGGCGAACGACCGCCGCATCGCGCATCGCCGTCGCGCGGCCTCCAAAAAAACGGCGGTCAGCGACCGCCGGCTTTGGCCGAAACCGATGCGTCGTACGAATCAGTGA
>   >gene_988|GeneMark.hmm|237_nt|+|1121027|1121263
>   ATGACCTTGTCAGGCAACATCAAGGACGGCGACTGGACGGTCGAGGTGACGACATCGCCGGTGCAGGGCGGTTACGTGTGCGACATCGAGGTGATGCACGGCGCGCCGGGCGGCGCGTTCCGGCACGCGTTCCGGCACGGCGGCACTTATCCGGCCGAGCGCGACGCGATGATCGAGGGGCTGCGCGCGGGCATGACCTGGATCGAGCTGAAGATGTCGAAAGCATTCAATCTGTAA
>   >gene_97|GeneMark.hmm|105_nt|+|90122|90226
>   GTGACGCGTTTCGCGACGCGCGTCGATGGGGCGGGCGCGAAACCCGTTCGCCGCGATGCGGCGGACGGGGTATGGCCGAGCGCCGTCCGTCGCGGCGAGAGTTGA
>   >gene_97|GeneMark.hmm|183_nt|-|107002|107184
>   ATGGAGGCAATCGTGATCGAGCAAGTGATACTGGGCGTCTTTCTCGTACTGCCGCTTCTCATCGTCGCGGTGCTGTACTCCGACGAACTCTGGCAAGAACACCGCCTGCAGCATCCGCGCGACGAGCACACGCCACATATCGACTGGCGTCATCCGTGGCGGATCCTGCGGCGAGGGCACTAA
>   >gene_97|GeneMark.hmm|189_nt|-|98624|98812
>   GTGAAATACACGAGCGACCATTACGCGGGCGTCAAATTTGGCGCGCTGTACGGGTTCTCGAACGCGGCGAACTTCGCCGACAACCGCGCTCGCCGGCGCATGCGCGGCGTTCGCATACGCGATCGGCAAAAGCGGCGTGATGTGCGGTTGCCTGCCGCGCTCGCGCTATGCGCGGCACGCCATCGATGA
>   >gene_97|GeneMark.hmm|234_nt|+|105494|105727
>   ATGAAGATTCAAATCGCCATTGTTTATTTTGTCGCCCGTCACGCAAACGAGCAGGCGCGAAGCGGATCGGCGCGCATTGGCGAAGAGCCGGCGCGCATCGGCATCGCGCTCGCGCGACACATGCGCGCCGCGCGCGGCCGGTCGACGCCGGATTCGCCTGTCGATCGATCCGGTGCGCCCCGAGCCGATGAGCGGTACGCTTCGGCGCGCGCGCGACACGCGCGACACGCGTGA
>   >gene_979|GeneMark.hmm|225_nt|-|1115442|1115666
>   TTGATCGACGCGCGGGGCCGGCCGGGCCGCGGGGTATCGAAGGCGATCGACGCGCAACACGAATCGCCGCCGCGCGCCGAAACCTCGCTATGCGCGTCGCGCGCACGCGCGGCCGGCGGCGCACGCGCGGGTGTGCGCGGGCCGGCGGCGCGGCCGCTCGCACTGCGCGACCGCTCGCGCGCACGCCTTCCTCGGCACGCGCCGGGAATCCCGGCCCTTCAATGA

The output that I expect is:

> >gene_579|GeneMark.hmm|237_nt|+|667187|667423
>   ATGTACCACGGCGCCGAATTTGCCGCTGCCAAGGGCATGCGCTGGCTGCGAGATGCCGCCAACGGCTCTGCCTTCATCGCACCGGGCAGTCCGTGGCAAAACGGTTTCGTCGAGCGTTTCAACGGCAAGCTGCATGACGAATTGCTGAACCGGGAATGGTTCCGCGGCCGTGCCGAGACCAAGATGCTCATCGAACGCTCCGGCTACGGTCCGTCGAGTCTGACCGGATTCCGATGA
>   >gene_3097|GeneMark.hmm|237_nt|-|3467022|3467258
>   GTGTCGAACGAACGTCGCGGCGAACGGCCGCTGCGGGCATCGCCGCAGGACGTCACACGGCGAACGTCGCGCGCGATCCTCGGCGGCCGCGAACGTGGGCCGTCCCGTGGCACGTTCGGCTCGCTCGGCATGGCGAACGACCGCCGCATCGCGCATCGCCGTCGCGCGGCCTCCAAAAAAACGGCGGTCAGCGACCGCCGGCTTTGGCCGAAACCGATGCGTCGTACGAATCAGTGA
>   >gene_988|GeneMark.hmm|237_nt|+|1121027|1121263
>   ATGACCTTGTCAGGCAACATCAAGGACGGCGACTGGACGGTCGAGGTGACGACATCGCCGGTGCAGGGCGGTTACGTGTGCGACATCGAGGTGATGCACGGCGCGCCGGGCGGCGCGTTCCGGCACGCGTTCCGGCACGGCGGCACTTATCCGGCCGAGCGCGACGCGATGATCGAGGGGCTGCGCGCGGGCATGACCTGGATCGAGCTGAAGATGTCGAAAGCATTCAATCTGTAA
>   >gene_97|GeneMark.hmm|183_nt|-|107002|107184
>   ATGGAGGCAATCGTGATCGAGCAAGTGATACTGGGCGTCTTTCTCGTACTGCCGCTTCTCATCGTCGCGGTGCTGTACTCCGACGAACTCTGGCAAGAACACCGCCTGCAGCATCCGCGCGACGAGCACACGCCACATATCGACTGGCGTCATCCGTGGCGGATCCTGCGGCGAGGGCACTAA
>   >gene_97|GeneMark.hmm|189_nt|-|98624|98812
>   GTGAAATACACGAGCGACCATTACGCGGGCGTCAAATTTGGCGCGCTGTACGGGTTCTCGAACGCGGCGAACTTCGCCGACAACCGCGCTCGCCGGCGCATGCGCGGCGTTCGCATACGCGATCGGCAAAAGCGGCGTGATGTGCGGTTGCCTGCCGCGCTCGCGCTATGCGCGGCACGCCATCGATGA

There are 4 sequences with gene number 97, but all in different length. I want the sequence with the correct gene length only which listed in file1.txt to output in the output.fasta file. What I've done so far is as follows (but failed and have some errors):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @genes;

open my $list, '<file1.txt';

while (my $line = <$list>) {
    push (@genes, $1) if $line =~/\>(.*?)\|/gs;
}

my $tag1 = "0\t"; 
my $tag2  = "nt"; 

while (my $line = <$list>) { 
    if ($line =~ /$tag1(.*?)$tag2/) {
        my $match1 = $1;
    } 
} 
my $input;

{
    local $/ = undef;
    open my $fasta, '<file2.fasta';
    my $tag3 = "GeneMark.hmm"; 
    my $tag4  = "_nt"; 
    while (my $input = <$fasta>) { 
        if ($input =~ /$tag3(.*?)$tag4/) { 
            my $match2 = $1; }} 
    close $fasta; 
}

my @lines = split(/>/,$input);
foreach my $l (@lines) {
    if ($l =~ /(.+?)\|/) {
        my $real_name = $1;
         if ($real_name ~~ @genes) {
            if ($match2 = $match1) {
            open (OUTFILE, '>>output.fasta');
            print OUTFILE ">$l"; }
         }
    }
}
```

Can anyone give me some guide to correct the code? Or is there any better way to do this? Any help will be very much appreciated! Thanks! :)

Comment: Please add the errors and your output also please.

Comment: @ka Error: Global symbol "$match2" requires explicit package name at mycode.pl line 35.  Global symbol "$match1" requires explicit package name at mycode.pl line 35. This is the error and no output. :(

Comment: Both `$match1` and `$match2` are declared within the scope of separate loops and by the time execution reaches `foreach my $l (@lines) {`, they are not in scope. Also, to test string equality, use `eq`. In `if ($match2 = $match1)` you are trying to assign the value of `$match1` to `$match2` and test that value.

Comment: Aren't there standard FASTA libraries out there?  Every few days we get some bioguys coming in that seem to be writing their own GATTACA handlers on their own.  Googling for "perl fasta" turns up all sorts of resources.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an option that uses [Bio::SeqIO](http://search.cpan.org/~cjfields/BioPerl-1.6.901/Bio/SeqIO.pm):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Bio::SeqIO;

my %hash;
open my $fh, '<', $ARGV[0] or die $!;

while (<$fh>) {
    push @{ $hash{$2} }, $1 if /\s+(\d+)nt,.+?>(gene_\d+)\|/;
}

close $fh;

my $in  = Bio::SeqIO->new( -file => $ARGV[1], -format => 'Fasta' );
my $out = Bio::SeqIO->new( -fh   => \*STDOUT, -format => 'Fasta' );

while ( my $seq = $in->next_seq() ) {
    $out->write_seq($seq)
      if $seq->id =~ /(gene_\d+)\|.+?\|(\d+)_nt\|/ and grep /$2/, @{ $hash{$1} };
}
```

Usage: `perl script.pl file1.txt file2.fasta [>outFile.fasta]`

The second, optional parameter directs output to a file.

Output from your data:

```
>gene_579|GeneMark.hmm|237_nt|+|667187|667423
ATGTACCACGGCGCCGAATTTGCCGCTGCCAAGGGCATGCGCTGGCTGCGAGATGCCGCC
AACGGCTCTGCCTTCATCGCACCGGGCAGTCCGTGGCAAAACGGTTTCGTCGAGCGTTTC
AACGGCAAGCTGCATGACGAATTGCTGAACCGGGAATGGTTCCGCGGCCGTGCCGAGACC
AAGATGCTCATCGAACGCTCCGGCTACGGTCCGTCGAGTCTGACCGGATTCCGATGA
>gene_3097|GeneMark.hmm|237_nt|-|3467022|3467258
GTGTCGAACGAACGTCGCGGCGAACGGCCGCTGCGGGCATCGCCGCAGGACGTCACACGG
CGAACGTCGCGCGCGATCCTCGGCGGCCGCGAACGTGGGCCGTCCCGTGGCACGTTCGGC
TCGCTCGGCATGGCGAACGACCGCCGCATCGCGCATCGCCGTCGCGCGGCCTCCAAAAAA
ACGGCGGTCAGCGACCGCCGGCTTTGGCCGAAACCGATGCGTCGTACGAATCAGTGA
>gene_988|GeneMark.hmm|237_nt|+|1121027|1121263
ATGACCTTGTCAGGCAACATCAAGGACGGCGACTGGACGGTCGAGGTGACGACATCGCCG
GTGCAGGGCGGTTACGTGTGCGACATCGAGGTGATGCACGGCGCGCCGGGCGGCGCGTTC
CGGCACGCGTTCCGGCACGGCGGCACTTATCCGGCCGAGCGCGACGCGATGATCGAGGGG
CTGCGCGCGGGCATGACCTGGATCGAGCTGAAGATGTCGAAAGCATTCAATCTGTAA
>gene_97|GeneMark.hmm|183_nt|-|107002|107184
ATGGAGGCAATCGTGATCGAGCAAGTGATACTGGGCGTCTTTCTCGTACTGCCGCTTCTC
ATCGTCGCGGTGCTGTACTCCGACGAACTCTGGCAAGAACACCGCCTGCAGCATCCGCGC
GACGAGCACACGCCACATATCGACTGGCGTCATCCGTGGCGGATCCTGCGGCGAGGGCAC
TAA
>gene_97|GeneMark.hmm|189_nt|-|98624|98812
GTGAAATACACGAGCGACCATTACGCGGGCGTCAAATTTGGCGCGCTGTACGGGTTCTCG
AACGCGGCGAACTTCGCCGACAACCGCGCTCGCCGGCGCATGCGCGGCGTTCGCATACGC
GATCGGCAAAAGCGGCGTGATGTGCGGTTGCCTGCCGCGCTCGCGCTATGCGCGGCACGC
CATCGATGA
```

Bio::SeqIO lives to parse fasta (and other such) files, so the above leverages this capability.  After creating a hash of arrays (HoA) from file1.txt, the fasta file is processed, and only matching fasta records are printed.

Hope this helps!